# Value of h:inputText is null in ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have the following code in JSF

```
<h:outputLabel value="Date" for="rdate" />
   <h:inputText id="rdate" autocomplete="off" 
       value="#{myMB.abstractProject.joinedDate}">
   </h:inputText>
```

and in Entity class, I have declared as

```
private Date joinedDate; 

public Date getJoinedDate() {
    return joinedDate;
}

public void setJoinedDate(Date joinedDate) {
    this.joinedDate= joinedDate;
}
```

The problem is, in ManagedBean I am getting null for the following

```
System.out.println("date in save method "
+ abstractRequest.getJoinedDate());
```

What could be the reason for this? `h:inputText` is infact in `<h:form>`. Scope of my bean is `@ViewAccessScoped`

Comment: Can you provide the code including the `<h:form>` and the `commandButton` that you use to submit the date?

Comment: @Mr.J4mes I have solved the issue, it was quite silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, the problem was there was an `Converter` error in another form element which stopped the form submit. I have used a `Converter` class to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`f:convertDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/). Like:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Date" for="rdate" />
<h:inputText id="rdate" autocomplete="off" value="#{myMB.abstractProject.joinedDate}" label="Date">
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-convertdatetime-example/) is an example.

### Edit:

Here is what I have done:

The xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" template="/WEB-INF/templates/globalTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">1532116</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">          
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel value="Date" for="date" />
            <h:inputText id="date" value="#{so15321163.date}" label="Date" required="true">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
            </h:inputText>              
            <h:message for="date" style="color:red" />              
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{so15321163.listener}"/>                   
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>    
</ui:composition>
```

The managed bean:

```
package app.so.dev.web.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="so15321163")
@ViewScoped // @SessionScoped
public class SO15321163 implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8012804893825661900L;
    private Date date;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    public void listener(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(date);
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Tapas I tried with `<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />`, however it is still null in ManagedBean

Comment: Hi @Polppan, did you mean `@ViewScoped`?

Comment: It is `@ViewAccessScoped` from `org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped`

Comment: @Polppan you are using MyFace, not Mojarra! I am able to print the Date in a listener using `ViewScoped` managed bean. However I am using Mojarra 2.1.7

Comment: I tried with `@SessionScoped`, but still no luck, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @Polppan I have provided the code that I did. And also it does work with `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`.

Comment: I have solved the issue, it was quite silly. Thanks Tapas for your help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but if you are missing the annotation @Named then jsf bean is not working properly.

Here is some more detailed explanation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/Conversations